# Binding sap.m.RadioButton

Tags: javascript, sapui5

how do I bind the selected property of `sap.m.RadioButtons`? I understood that I group them with the `groupName` property but I'm totally missing sth. like `RadioButtonGroup` to get the selected key or alike. `sap.m.RadioButton` does not even provide a key? Could someone give an example?

```
<RadioButton groupName="MyGroup" text="Option A" selected="true" />
<RadioButton groupName="MyGroup" text="Option B" />
```

Say my model looks like this:

```
{ currentOption: "A" }
{ options : [ { "name" : "A" }, { "name" : "B" } ] }
```

The alternative option would be "B". How to map this?

BR
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can use the property groupName to group the RadioButtons and with property selected you set the selected RadioButton.
The binding can be done as usual, you would bind the text against your name and if you would like to bind the selection as well, then you would have to put this into your data as well. Your data would look like this:

{ options : [ { "name" : "A", "selected" : "true" }, { "name" : "B" }, "selected" : "false" ] }

If you have a look at www.github.com/SAP/openui5/ you can check the master branch, there is already a sap.m.RadioButtonGroup which you can use for testing. It will probably come with the next release.

BR,
Janina